# Waiting for WebBrowser to fully load between multiple Navigate() calls

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, user-controls, webbrowser-control

I am venturing into WPF - first time in (VB).NET -  and trying to re-create a project I started in MS Access VBA. It basically scrapes a series of pages within a web application. As you may have surmised I am having trouble with the LoadCompleted event.

I have searched and found some information on it, but the "flow" of the code only lends itself to waiting for one page to load. For example:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nn-NO/wpf/thread/52c1bc55-dd41-468c-8759-a42726635d4b

All of the code execution is run in the DocumentLoaded event which works fine when you just need to navigate to one page and execute code. But I need to perform a series of these cycles for my application.

How can I reliably wait for the document to fully load while still keeping the code execution in the same Sub AND not locking the UI thread?

Here's a basic idea of what I'm trying to do.

1. Navigate to page
2. Wait for page to fully load
3. do stuff
4. Navigate to page
5. Rinse, Repeat

P.S - .NET is very new to me so please don't give my brain a stack overflow ;)

Thanks,
Brian

**-## EDIT ##-**

This is what I use to do in VBA. This is exactly what I'm trying to do, just in the ".NET" way and without blocking the UI Thread:

```
Dim oIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

        With oIE
            .Navigate(strURL)
            .Visible = False


           ' loop until the page finishes loading
           Do While oIE.Busy : Loop
           Do While oIE.ReadyState <> 4 : Loop

           'Code goes here to read DOM, get fields and click a button (logging in to site)
           'My code execution is done and now I'm ready to go to the next page and read the DOM

           .Navigate(strURL)

        End With
```

.
.
.
.

That's it. Repeat for *n* times. my interactions with each DOM are significantly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just call `Navigate` again at the end of the `LoadCompleted` handler.  Then, I guess, use a window-scoped variable to keep track of your target URLs.

```
List<string> _urls;
int _i = 0;
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _urls = new List<string>() { url1, url2, url3 };    // URLs to navigate
    webBrowser1.LoadCompleted += webBrowser1_LoadCompleted;
    webBrowser1.Navigate(_urls[_i]);
}
void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff

    i++;
    var nextUrl = _urls[i];
    webBrowser1.Navigate(nextUrl);
}
```

**EDIT**

Maybe something like this would be more suitable.  After each cycle, you can set up the next URL as well as its handler.

```
class NavIteration
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public delegate void HandleResult(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e);
    public HandleResult ResultHandler { get; set; }
}

NavIteration CurrentIteration;

void setNextIteration()
{
    CurrentIteration = null;
    CurrentIteration = new NavIteration() { 
        Url = someurl, 
        ResultHandler = (sender, e) => {
            // handle
        }
    };
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.LoadCompleted += webBrowser1_LoadCompleted;
    setNextIteration();
    webBrowser1.Navigate();
}

void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentIteration.ResultHandler(sender, e);
    setNextIteration();
    webBrowser1.Navigate(CurrentIteration.Url);
}
```

Comment: dbaseman, thanks for replying. Unfortunately the URLs that I am navigating to are not known. In other words, the number of URLs required and the URL themselves are dynamically generated after each "cycle"

Comment: @brian gotcha.  Wouldn't it be the same in principle though?  Just call some implementation of **getNextUrl()** and away you go?

Comment: Ahh, I see. You're saying I can add items to the list on the fly as I am iterating though the list. But my actions (code) for each URL is different. Am I just going to have a huge SELECT..Case to handle each URL? Since I don't know the URL until it is the next page in the list, how can I match the browsers current URL to the appropriate code block? I hope I'm asking the question clearly enough. I appreciate you offering me your time to help. Thank you.

Comment: No prob ... I guess it depends.  Is the code completely different for each URL?  Or can you write a single function with some parameters to handle all cases?  Or can you group the handler code based on some type of category?

Comment: It's quite different - sometimes I'm just reading values, other times I am sending input or invoking a javascript function. I'm shocked there's not a better alternative for this..

Comment: @brian There probably is, but I'm finding it hard to see what that would be without knowing what your goal is exactly.  I took another crack at it though-- see my edit above.

Comment: I'm having some trouble translating that to VB.NET. But what I'm looking to can't be this complicated. This is what I used to do in VBA:

`

Comment: The code didn't come through.  Can you post it in the question?

Comment: I revisited your original suggestion, and with a few enhancements, I think I have a plan that will work. I need to track a few more variables than just the URL so I am writing them to a temporary DB and calling the variables based on the current URL. Once I have the current URL and the variables I call a class that handles the work for each specific page. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am way off but I would "do stuff" in a `BackGroundWorker`.  Let the primary thread do nothing but find pages.  If "do stuff" is slower than find then throttle find next.

Have you considered WebClient to download to String or Byte array and then convert to DOM.   Is there something in IE you need?

Comment: Hi Blam - the "stuff" in this case is scraping data from the browsers DOM. I can't see how the BGW could help. No matter what thread it runs on it still needs to wait for IE to fully load. Having to make multiple calls to the WebBrowser and having it all dump out on the event handler is making this a challenge for me.

Comment: @brian See updated answer.  If you cannot see how do stuff on a BGW would help then I doubt I can help you.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand what you're proposing? I'm 5 days into .NET. So on the click event of a button I code it to navigate to the page. Then "run" a BGW to read the dom of the page. I'm still stuck with the same issue. I can't start reading the DOM until the browser finishes loading. It's not a matter of doing two things simultaneously. It's doing one thing and getting acknowledgement that it completed before I move to the next thing, then rinse/repeat. I'd prefer not to lock my app in the process but at this point I don't even care if it means getting it to do what I want.

Comment: I'm interacting with each page on the site. So I can't just pull the DOM down. I need to read elements, click controls, etc for each page I'm going to.